# How can I convince my 28-month-old it's ok to poop?

Tags: toddler, potty-training

My 28-month-old girl absolutely refuses to poop. We started potty training a week ago and she does perfect with pee. But she went to poop and freaked out. Crying and gagging is all I got... That was on a Monday, it's now Saturday morning and not more poop. She even told me I don't want to poop ever never...

Please help! I figured by now it would have to come out... Apparently not... We've tried everything big potty little potty rewards... I hate to give her something to go and her have diarrhea.

Comment: Hi, Natalie, and welcome to the site. Sometimes toddlers are frightened of disposing of part of themselves (I know it sounds strange, but children see the world differently). She needs time and coaxing. The answer in the duplicate and others may give you ideas (see the list on the right of your screen or search the site using the search function). If you still have questions not addressed by those posts, please ask your new question. Again, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Give in on this one, my friend.  When she is ready to poop, allow her to use a diaper.  Just tell her once in a while, in a warm, friendly way, that when she's a little older, she will poop in the toilet like Mama and Papa.

Don't worry.  She will eventually poop in the toilet like Mama and Papa.

There's no rush with this at 24 months.

Try not to get into a tug of war with her -- you'll have plenty of unavoidable conflicts with her later on.  For now, try to enjoy life with her as much as you can.